# Origin of "Indent" as in inventory or request

Tags: etymology, british-english, phrase-origin

I have recently moved to an institution run by the British government where staff use the term "indent" as a noun to refer to an inventory exercise done to work out what they need to buy.

This is consistent with several dictionaries, such as [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/indent):

> chiefly British
>
> - a
>   : an official requisition
> - b
>   : a purchase order for goods especially when sent from a foreign country

Does anybody know where this usage comes from?

Comment: The full OED has that specific sense as **indent** 4. *An official requisition for stores. (**Originally by a covenanted servant of the East India Company**)*.

Comment: ...for the etymology, they say *Etymology: < French endenter (Ph. de Thaun, 12th cent.) ‘to snip, notch, iag on the edges’ (Cotgrave), Latin type *indentāre (medieval Latin indentare and Italian indentare ), < in- (in- prefix3) + *dentāre to furnish with teeth, < dens , dent-em tooth; compare dentātus dentate adj.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers - is that not an answer?

Comment: @Heartspring: I don't think so, no. I've just spent a few minutes trawling Google Books and the Internet at large to try and get a handle on how exactly this highly specific meaning arose. The full OED's first 3 citations are ***all*** from the Duke of Wellington's "dispatches", between 1799 and 1803, but that tells me nothing about *why*. Someone else may know more.

Comment: ...could "a ***covenanted*** servant" mean an ***indentured*** servant? Is that relevant?

Comment: **indenture** (noun) 2b. spec. *The contract by which an apprentice is bound to the master; also the contract by which a person binds himself or herself to **service in the colonies**, etc.*

Comment: It's the same idea as bookmarking - you turn over the page corner or otherwise mark the item for future reference. French was the language of bureaucracy in England, don't forget.

Comment: @FumbleFingers — I think you picked the wrong sense of *indent*; see:  **5**. *Commerce.* An order for goods, esp. one sent to England from abroad. (*OED*)

Comment: A paper on the accounting practices of the Hudson Bay Company that explains the term: https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/288025177.pdf [founded in **1670**] The physical count of inventories was the starting point for an indent.

Comment: Indent Books (n)
Requisitions for the outfit two years in advance, e.g. orders made out in 1840 were shipped in 1841 for outfit 1842. The goods are listed alphabetically noting quantity and kind, together with other general remarks. The early indents are listed according to the various stores at the York Factory Depot in which the commodities were kept, i.e. Shipwright's Store, Cooper's Store, Naval Store, etc. https://www.gov.mb.ca/chc/archives/hbca/resource/post_rec/types.html

Comment: In Middle English (15th c) we have the word **indent|endent** (spelling variants) that means a written agreement.  It goes back to **endenture** which had multiple related meanings including the one in question, but the word had entered English and we have the attested plural **indents**.

Answer (score 0):

My search engine threw up many citations telling us 'indenture' comes from medieval English "indenture of retainer" — a legal contract written in duplicate on the same sheet, with the copies separated by cutting along an irregular line so that the 'teeth' of the two parts could later be refitted to confirm authenticity - 'teeth' here being from French 'dent' from Latin 'dentis.'

That much sounds exactly like the idea of sealing a pact by ripping a playing-cark, bank-note, coin or medallion in two, so often seen at least in fiction to allow gangsters, missing heirs or saviours-of-the-world to claim treasure or favours.

There also seems to have been a point when ‘indented’ meant merely marked, not the matching-pair-marked above. Isn’t that perfectly equivalent to ‘ear-marking’ livestock?

How huge a hike is it from ‘That pile of stuff has been indented…’ through ‘This is to inform you of the indenting of that pile of stuff…’ to ‘This is an indent for a matching pile of stuff…’ and on to ‘This is an indent for some stuff…’?

Comment: and see also split tally sticks, in which debts and loans were coded on sticks that were then spit lengthwise and broken off at the end. The long part was retained by the lender and the short part was held by the debtor. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tally_stick

Comment: Yes, Phil, clearly. I simply forgot to mention them.